# Does Ubuntu have a driver for the EVGA GeForce GTX760?

Tags: drivers

the graphics card i want to buy only has drivers for windows and I was wondering if ubuntu had any drivers for the:

EVGA GeForce GTX760 FTW with ACX Cooler 4GB GDDR5 256Bit Dual-Link DVI-I DVI-D HDMI DP SLI Ready 04G-P4-3768-KR

Comment: Your question should be "Does this company provide a Linux driver?". It's not Ubuntu's responsibility to create drivers.

Comment: I think that comment and the downvotes were a bit harsh. The linux kernel contains all sort of drivers, including graphics drivers for intel and ati and nvidia. I agree perhaps the question could have been better worded.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it works with Linux. Download the driver from NVidia. You can even apt-get install from the Ubuntu repository. Use 340.x