# Multiple monitors freeze and have artifacts when logging in

Tags: multiple-monitors, startup

When I boot into Ubuntu on my computer 2/3 times the monitors will freeze and the system will become unresponsive. I have triple monitors. This is what is looks like when it freezes. All of the monitors have this:

[image]

Any idea why this might be happening? The monitors all work perfectly fine when I boot into Windows.

EDIT: 
System specs:

- Intel Core i7 3770k @ 4.5
- EVGA GeForce GTX 660ti
- 16gb RAM

Comment: what wireless card ? Unity only or other DE (kde, xfce, lxde)

Comment: Nice screens, like my new ones! (Only dual here tho)

Comment: @Bodhi do you mean graphics card?

Comment: I added an edit with the system specs

Answer (score 0):

You said that you have the

```
EVGA GeForce 660ti
```

graphics card.

The EVGA graphics card are not supported by Linux, they don't provide drivers for it...

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/550358/) question.

Comment: But how would that explain it working sometimes. If it was not supported shouldn't it just not work at all?

Comment: Ubuntu works in mysterious ways... No honestly I don't know I'm afraid... Some things do seem to be quite random whether they work or not...

Comment: So is there just no fix then? Or is it just an Ubuntu/Debian problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same graphics card and monitor as you. I get the same problem, and I have been unplugging my monitors before I turn it on and plugging them back in. That seems to fix the problem, but there might be a better way.

Comment: Might work but not a solution. I switched over to Elementary OS for now and everything works fine out of the box.